# Can't See When Using LiveDVD, Blind Booting

Tags: boot

I have 8 discs, currently. All LTSs, half 32-bit, half 64-bit, half KDE, half Gnome.

The 32-bit ones, my computer can't read. The 64-bit ones work, but the pixels are extremely messed up. Everything is scrambled for some reason. I press up and down and I can see things happening, but I don't know what. So, I need to know how to do this blindly.

Which option, in the boot menu of 12.04, will start the BootFromDVD? First one down? Second one down? I press down how many times? Then, once I press Enter or Right, what do I press? Guide the blind man through the maze.

Thanks!

Comment: Would it be possible to attach a screenshot? This is possibly a driver issue. See if this answer helps: [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/a/162076)